# Downloading images from web and its attributes in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I want to download the images of this site https://moweek.com.uy/ in R, specifically, those under the class = "expandedCategory": "VESTIMENTA", "CALZADO", "ACCESORIOS" (data-category-id="1", data-category-id="2", and data-category-id="3"). For example, go into the sub categories () under "VESTIMENTA" (except from "Ver todo") like "Activewear" (<a data-category-id="57" href="/vestimenta/activewear/1" class=" categoryLevelTwoTitle selected'>Activewear == $0) clicking in all the images and obtain all of the information in a dataset as well as the images.

I've trying to do this but I am failing.

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, rvest, httr)

url <- "https://moweek.com.uy/"
html_content <- GET(url)
webpage <- read_html(content(html_content, as = "text"))

category_nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, ".expandedCategory")

category_urls <- lapply(category_nodes, function(node) html_nodes(node, "a") %>% 
                          html_attr("href")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_subset("/vestimenta/|/calzado/|/accesorios/")
                 
image_data <- data.frame()
for (url in category_urls) {
  cat_url <- paste0("https://moweek.com.uy", url)
  cat_content <- GET(cat_url)
  cat_page <- read_html(content(cat_content, as = "text"))
  
  # Extract the category name and the subcategory name from the page title
  cat_name <- html_text(html_node(cat_page, "title")) %>%
    str_replace("- MoWeek", "") %>%
    str_to_title()
  subcat_name <- html_text(html_node(cat_page, ".categoryLevelTwoTitle")) %>%
    str_to_title()
  
  # Extract the image information from the page and store it in a data frame
  image_tags <- html_nodes(cat_page, ".productItem")
  image_info <- data.frame()
  for (tag in image_tags) {
    name <- html_text(html_node(tag, ".productTitle"))
    price <- html_text(html_node(tag, ".priceText"))
    img_url <- html_attr(html_node(tag, "img"), "src")
    image_info <- image_info %>%
      add_row(Category = cat_name,
              Subcategory = subcat_name,
              Name = name,
              Price = price,
              Image_URL = img_url)
  }
  image_data <- image_data %>% bind_rows(image_info)
}

for (i in 1:nrow(image_data)) {
  img <- GET(image_data$Image_URL[i])
  category <- image_data$Category[i]
  subcategory <- image_data$Subcategory[i]
  category_folder <- gsub(" ", "_", category)
  subcategory_folder <- gsub(" ", "_", subcategory)
  
  if (!dir.exists(category_folder)) {
    dir.create(category_folder)
  }
  if (!dir.exists(paste0(category_folder, "/", subcategory_folder))) {
    dir.create(paste0(category_folder, "/", subcategory_folder))
  }
  
  file_name <- paste
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem in your code? Do you get any error or warning messages? If so, what are they? If not, why do the results differ from your expectation?

Comment: The image_data is generated but with 0 colums and 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seemed to work for me.

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest)
library(httr)

url <- "https://moweek.com.uy/"
html_content <- GET(url)
webpage <- read_html(content(html_content, as = "text"))

category_nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, ".expandedCategory")

category_urls <- lapply(category_nodes, function(node) html_nodes(node, "a") %>% 
                          html_attr("href")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_subset("/vestimenta/|/calzado/|/accesorios/")

image_data <- tibble()
for (url in category_urls) {
  cat_url <- paste0("https://moweek.com.uy", url)
  # Because we are sending so many requests, some are likely to fail
  cat_content <- RETRY("GET", cat_url)
  cat_page <- read_html(content(cat_content, as = "text"))
  
  # Extract the category name and the subcategory name from the page title
  cat_name <- html_text(html_node(cat_page, "title")) %>%
    str_replace("- MoWeek", "") %>%
    str_to_title()
  subcat_name <- html_text(html_node(cat_page, ".categoryLevelTwoTitle")) %>%
    str_to_title()
  
  # Extract the image information from the page and store it in a data frame
  image_tags <- html_nodes(cat_page, ".productViewContainer")
  # Initialise columns so bind_rows() works
  image_info <- tibble(
    Category = character(),
    Subcategory = character(),
    Name = character(),
    Price = character(),
    Image_URL = character()
  )
  for (tag in image_tags) {
    name <- html_text(html_node(tag, ".productViewName"))
    price <- html_text(html_node(tag, ".productViewPrice"))
    img_url <- html_attr(html_node(tag, ".productViewTop"), "data-hover-image")
    image_info <- image_info %>%
      add_row(Category = cat_name,
              Subcategory = subcat_name,
              Name = name,
              Price = price,
              Image_URL = img_url)
  }
  image_data <- image_data %>% bind_rows(image_info)
}

# Clean data
image_data <- image_data %>%
  mutate(
    Name = str_trim(Name),
    Price = str_trim(Price)
  )

# Get the file name of each image
file_names <- str_match(image_data$Image_URL, ".+(/.*?$)")[,2] %>%
  str_sub(start = 2L)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(image_data))) {
  url <- image_data$Image_URL[i]
  category <- image_data$Category[i]
  subcategory <- image_data$Subcategory[i]
  category_folder <- gsub(" ", "_", category)
  subcategory_folder <- gsub(" ", "_", subcategory)
  
  if (!dir.exists(category_folder)) {
    dir.create(category_folder)
  }
  if (!dir.exists(paste0(category_folder, "/", subcategory_folder))) {
    dir.create(paste0(category_folder, "/", subcategory_folder))
  }
  
  # Download and store image in correct directory
  dir_name <- paste0(category_folder, "/", subcategory_folder, "/")
  file_name <- file_names[i]
  download.file(url, paste0(dir_name, file_name))
}
```